# SSIS package executes fine from my machine, but failing as a SQL job

Tags: c#, sql-server, ssis, etl, sql-job

I have an SSIS package which uses C# script and 3rd party libraries to perform the required task. The package executes fine from visual studio, however when I try to run the same as SQL job, I see a successful completion, however the task the script is expected to perform is not happening (The 3rd party dll methods appears to be ignored).

The SQL job is run using service account and for Visual studio it is with my windows user credentials.

Is it a credentials issue for the service user or a firewall issue, any suggestions which can direct me to a way forward will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: You will need to perhaps post a snippet of code, and maybe list some of the dependencies?

Answer (score 0):

One time, I faced a similar issue while using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.dll` assembly, after spending my time trying to resolve this issue, I some functionalities require a Windows user to run without any error.

Try to add a proxy account *(run SQL job with the same credentials use to run manually)*, you can follow one of these links for a step-by-step answer.

- [Running a SSIS Package from SQL Server Agent Using a Proxy Account](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2163/running-a-ssis-package-from-sql-server-agent-using-a-proxy-account/)
- [Create a SQL Server Agent Proxy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-sql-server-agent-proxy)

Answer (score 0):

How do you load the reference to the 3rd party in your script?
I guess you are experiencing dll loading issue while running your code as a SQL Job. 
Can you provide more details?